# No module named _mysql - Google App Engine & Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine

First of all I'm working on **Mac (Yosemite)**.

I've created a simple **Django** project with **Google App Engine**. I'm using **Cloud SQL** in production and **MySQL** in development environment as recommended in the docs. The project uses **virtualenv** on my dev machine of course.

I can run the project with Django's built in **runserver** command without a problem and even if I deploy it to GAE everything is fine.

However if I run the development server with GAE launcher it raises an error whenever I try to load a page:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql
```

I installed the same version of MySQLdb that GAE has. Currently its 1.2.4.
MySQLdb is available for GAE SDK so I have no idea why it cannot import _mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally found a workaround.

Simply adding **MySQLdb** to your **GAE** lib is not enough. MySQLdb tries to import **_mysql** which is a .so or .c file depends on what version of MySQLdb you use. It seems like importing them directly is not working correctly I suppose. Maybe because it's a low-level C file and as it's stated in the docs GAE does not support any kind of C extensions. If you know a better explanation please share us in the comment section.

**The solution:**

First of all I had to rename **_mysql.so**. Mine is just **mysql.so** now.

Then create a file named **_mysql.py** in the same directory and put this code in it:

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'mysql.so') #point to your renamed _mysql.so
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

GAE should import now MySQLdb without errors.

Comment: No need to rename _mysql.so to mysql.so

Comment: For me it worked only after renaming _mysql.so to mysql.so